# Установка готовой postgresql с базами данных

Tags: windows, postgresql

Есть программа к ней идет база данных `postgresql` которая устанавливалась отдельно вместе с сервером. Как сделать чтобы при установке данной программы устанавливался и сервер `postgresql` с данной базой данных.
OC: Windows

Comment: Какой инсталлятор используете? Как вообще программа устанавливается?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov использую smart installer так как надо просто переносить файлы в определенную папку. А вот с postgresql проблема уже.

Comment: В чём проблема дёрнуть установщик `pg` с нужными тебе опциями?